# How To make dbContext DBSet<Anyclass> Method for getting last value of given Entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created specific method which retrieving last [Code] value from the product table, I want to retrieve code from other tables too, kindly suggest me how to create generic Methods,
specific Class Code.

```
    public static string GetCode(SDMSDbContext dbContext)
    {
        string lastProductCode = string.Empty;

        var LastProduct = dbContext.Products.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (LastProduct != null)
            lastProductCode = LastProduct.Code;

        return lastProductCode.GenerateNextCode("PC");
    }
```

And NextNumber Code.

```
    public static string GenerateNextCode(this string code, string identifier)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
            return "${identifier}-000001";

        var newProductCode = Convert.ToInt32(code.Split(new char[] { '-' })[1]) + 1;

        return $"{identifier}-{newProductCode.ToString().PadLeft(6, '0')}";
    }
```

And I want something like.

```
    public static string GetLastCode(SDMSDbContext sDMSDbContext,DbSet AnyClass)
    {
        _dbContext = sDMSDbContext;
        string lastCode = string.Empty;

        var LastProduct = _dbContext.entities.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        if (LastProduct != null)
            lastCode = LastProduct.Code;

        return lastProductCode.GenerateNextCode("SO");
    }
```

Comment: can you share a sample project, so we can test and give you an answer?

Comment: well it's office software I don't have rights for sharing